# Playing with OF and CF in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

today I am learning how to read Carry Flag and Overflow Flag in assembly x86 using Emu8086 for Windows.

I learned that in unsigned math, I need to look at Carry Flag while in signed math, I need to look at overflow flag: and this should be fine. I tried to do this:

```
MOV AX, 0FFFFH
INC AX
```

in unsigned math, 0xFFFF is a number with 16 ones so, adding 1, the carry flag should be setted to 1 right? But it's 0! So, I tried to do this

```
MOV AX, 0FFFFH
ADD AX, 1
```

now the Carry Flag is setted to one. Why? Is it a bug or another thing?
Thank you

Comment: It's not a bug. `INC` doesn't modify the carry flag by definition, [see here section AFlags](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INC.html). `ADD` - on the other hand - does.

Comment: Oh.. well! thank you!

Comment: It's special feature of x86 `inc/dec` instructions, to make them viable for loop counters while doing operations like adding of arbitrary precision values, where you want to preserve carry flag for every loop iteration, or when you want to shift bits across larger area of memory, etc..

Comment: You can check if there is carry-out from `inc` by testing for zero. That is, `jz`, instead of `jc`.